# How to run a bash script to update a Rails app from outside its directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, rake

I have this script that should be running from the `/~` directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
APP=/root/apps/monitoring
cd $APP
git pull
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
touch $APP/tmp/restart.txt
```

As you can see, it pulls new commits and updates the assets and restarts Apache. The problem is when it runs the line `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`, It says:

```
Could not find proper version of rake (12.1.0) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Which is strange because I am supposed to be inside the app's folder (/root/apps/monitoring) when this command is executed. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to load rvm in the script (https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting) and may be select proper ruby/gemset.

Also you can consider using wrapper for `bundle` created with `rvm wrapper`

Comment: How do I create this wrapper? I RVM is already loaded on the script even without sourcing it. Probably the problem is that gemset is not sourced, because it does not find the gems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The gemset used wasn't my app's. I fixed it by using `rvm gemset use monitoring`.

Comment: Also you can run single command with `rvm 2.3.3@my-gemset do bundle exec rake  foo`

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
#!/bin/bash
APP=/root/apps/monitoring
cd $APP
git pull
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
touch $APP/tmp/restart.txt
```

With `bundle exec` it should work.

Comment: Did not work, It now says that rake is not installed. And asking to run bundle install to fix it. I tried to run Bundle install but it said that couldn't locate Gemfile. If I run bundle install inside app's folder, everything is OK.

Comment: Yes, I use RVM. I used rvm list rubies at /~ and it is the same ruby version I am using in the app.

Comment: Ok then I would try `rvm use your-ruby-version` before `cd $APP`. Does this help? Maybe you need also to source your .bashrc, i.e., `source ~/.bashrc; rvm use ...; cd $APP; ...`

Comment: Tried, did not work. It said:
`RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work. You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell. Sometimes it is required to use '/bin/bash --login' as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.`

I am running it as Root. So, is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: How about using a login shell, i.e., `#!/bin/bash --login` in the first line. Maybe this helps?

Answer (score 1):

I run rake tasks using bash script wrappers. The trick is to use the source command to load in the rvm environment after the task is started

example.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# change the directory
cd /home/ubuntu/GSeries
# load rvm ruby
source /home/ubuntu/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.4.2@mygemset
bundle exec rake  db:prune_logs RAILS_ENV="production" &>> /home/ubuntu/GSeries/log/prune_logs.log
```